# Is There Any Historical Evidence for the Resurrection of Jesus like some papers or something?

Tags: history, resurrection-of-jesus, historical-jesus, historical-criticism, herod

Is there any historical evidence for the resurrection of Jesus like some papers or something or from some sources that are not from the bible .

I am asking this because an atheist said to me something like the following:

> Give me a Roman newspaper with “MAN CRUCIFIED ARISES FROM CAVE!” dated
>   around 30 AD and I’ll take your assertion seriously.

I have searched the web and only find some translated messages a the following:

[The Messages of Pontius Pilate and Herod](http://www.arabchurch.com/forums/showthread.php?t=152778)

[The text of Nazareth is a historical guide to the resurrection of Christ from the tomb](https://drghaly.com/articles/display/12828)

However it needs translation into English.
I don't know why the first article author didn't mention the reference with links. He just said:

> These messages are located in a Syriac manuscript in the British Museum, dated to the sixth or seventh century there is a Greek copy in a Museum in Paris

Comment: Welcome! This question has already been asked, so this one has been closed as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @Nathaniel pls remove the mark i have already looked at these questions and their answers and non was a valid answer or source/reference to my question 
...
you should look to the answers yourself before marking this as an duplicate..
thanks